# Returning path that is different between local and live server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using a method like this in order to get the URL path of my application:

```
string strPathAndQuery = HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
string strUrl = HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(strPathAndQuery, "/");
```

This is supposed to path to the current URL.

The problem is, my live server runs the application as an application (folder) inside an IIS server.  So when testing a I get a URL like:

```
http://localhost/Survey/Create
```

And live I get:

```
http://testurl.com/Survey/Create
```

When what I need for the live server is:

```
http://testurl.com/SurveyApp/Survey/Create
```

With SurveyApp being the folder that stores the application in IIS.  Is there a way that I can get the URL of where the controllers are located, regardless of physical location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC has methods for this reason, such as Url.Content.  These will resolve the currect url when you use an app dir relative path like "~/Survey/Query".  You would also use methods like Html.ActionLink or Url.Action to get url's to specific action methods.  These will adjust to your correct path.

Can you be more specific about WHY you are trying to get the path?

Comment: I am using a mailing component to send queued email and need to include a link to a specific controller and action.  Since it's the body message of a mail component I didn't think I could use Razor Syntax.

Comment: @user547794 - The methods I mention have nothing to do with Razor, other than you can call them from Razor.  However, you will have to massage them a little to get the absolute path (these methods only provide relative URL's)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add ~ sign in front of the relative URIs. For example, to link `/Survey/Query` use `~/Survey/Query`

Edit:

What about `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` ?

Comment: That does not work in MVC apps, unless you use specific methods that are virtual path aware.

Answer (score 0):

Url.Content is what you want.  Something like:

```
string url = Url.Content("Query", "Survey");
```

First argument is the Action, second is the Controller.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758

There are also quite a few overloads you can use.